# Postgresql unnest with ordinality as well as times seen

Tags: arrays, postgresql

Let's say I have an array of potentially duplicated strings

`[a,a,b,c,a,b,c,d]`

I'd like to unnest array this so that I can get the index, as well as a count for how many times that element has already been unnested within the array. All my arrays are relatively short (25 elements or fewer).

My expected output would be:

```
a, 1, 1
a, 2, 2
b, 3, 1
c, 4, 1
a, 5, 3
b, 6, 2
c, 7, 2
d, 8, 1
```

I can do the first two bits quite easily with
 `left join lateral unnest(arr) with ordinality as a(element, idx)`, but I'd like the times_seen part also.

Comment: What version of postgres?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `COUNT` analytic function

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/66c9e9/5)

**PostgreSQL 9.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t
    (arr TEXT[])
;

INSERT  
    INTO t (arr)
         VALUES ('{a,a,b,c,a,b,c,d}'::TEXT[])
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT element
    ,idx
    ,COUNT(element) OVER (
        PARTITION BY element ORDER BY idx
        ) AS times_seen
FROM t
    ,unnest(arr) WITH ordinality AS a(element, idx)
ORDER BY idx
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/66c9e9/5/0)**:

```
| element | idx | times_seen |
|---------|-----|------------|
|       a |   1 |          1 |
|       a |   2 |          2 |
|       b |   3 |          1 |
|       c |   4 |          1 |
|       a |   5 |          3 |
|       b |   6 |          2 |
|       c |   7 |          2 |
|       d |   8 |          1 |
```

If you may multiple rows containing arrays and have an ID column for each array, you may use

`PARTITION BY ID,element` to get the count values for the array at that specific id.

Comment: Nice. I was going to post an answer with ARRAY_POSITIONS using an array slice to get the times seen, but this is better.